# Invalid provider type specified when trying to access google analytics

Tags: asp.net, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-dotnet-client, service-accounts

We keep getting the error below whenever we try to access the API to get current user numbers. I've tried a few things but cannot get to the bottom of this. Can anyone shed any light on whats wrong/missing?

I should point out that thus runs perfectly fine on my local PC but is failing on the server.

Here is the error:

> ConnectToAnalytics error:
>   System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Invalid provider
>   type specified. at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.Utils.CreateProvHandle(CspParameters
>   parameters, Boolean randomKeyContainer) at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.Utils.GetKeyPairHelper(CspAlgorithmType
>   keyType, CspParameters parameters, Boolean randomKeyContainer, Int32
>   dwKeySize, SafeProvHandle& safeProvHandle, SafeKeyHandle&
>   safeKeyHandle) at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.GetKeyPair() at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider..ctor(Int32
>   dwKeySize, CspParameters parameters, Boolean useDefaultKeySize) at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2.get_PrivateKey()
>   at
>   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer.FromCertificate(X509Certificate2
>   certificate) in
>   C:\Users\mdril\Documents\GitHub\google-api-dotnet-client\Src\GoogleApis.Auth.DotNet4\OAuth2\ServiceAccountCredential.cs:line
>   100 at Core.ConnectToAnalytics()

This error is thrown when i run the code:

```
Public Shared Function GetRealtimeUsers() As String
    Try
        'realtime on site
        Dim gsService As AnalyticsService = Core.ConnectToAnalytics
        Dim RequestRealtime As DataResource.RealtimeResource.GetRequest = gsService.Data.Realtime.[Get]([String].Format("ga:{0}", "xxxxx"), "rt:activeUsers")
        Dim feed As RealtimeData = RequestRealtime.Execute()

        Return Int(feed.Rows(0)(0)).ToString()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return "QUOTA USED"
    End Try
```

It error's here: RequestRealtime.Execute()

For reference - here's the connect script:

```
Public Shared Function ConnectToAnalytics() As AnalyticsService
    Try
        Dim scopes As String() = New String() {AnalyticsService.Scope.Analytics, AnalyticsService.Scope.AnalyticsEdit, AnalyticsService.Scope.AnalyticsManageUsers, AnalyticsService.Scope.AnalyticsReadonly}
        Dim keyFilePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("\xxx.p12")
        Dim serviceAccountEmail = "xxx"
        Dim certificate = New X509Certificate2(keyFilePath, "xxxx", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable)
        Dim credential = New ServiceAccountCredential(New ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail) With {.Scopes = scopes}.FromCertificate(certificate))
        Return New AnalyticsService(New BaseClientService.Initializer() With {.HttpClientInitializer = credential, .ApplicationName = "Client for xxx"})
    Catch ex As Exception
        Core.SendAdminStatusReport("ConnectToAnalytics error: " & ex.ToString)
        Throw ex
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: Its a Cryptography error.   Please edit your question and include a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve there is not enough information here to find the issue.

Comment: Updated as best i could

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this - i was on the right lines with root certificates, turns out i was missing one. These can be found here:

https://pki.goog/

I cannot remember where i found this but adding the code below to the webconfig helped me figure out which certificate i was missing:

```
 <system.diagnostics>
<trace autoflush="true" />
<sources>
  <source name="System.Net">
    <listeners>
      <add name="System.Net"/>
    </listeners>
  </source>
  <source name="System.Net.HttpListener">
    <listeners>
      <add name="System.Net"/>
    </listeners>
  </source>
  <source name="System.Net.Sockets">
    <listeners>
      <add name="System.Net"/>
    </listeners>
  </source>
  <source name="System.Net.Cache">
    <listeners>
      <add name="System.Net"/>
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
<sharedListeners>
  <add
   name="System.Net"
   type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
    initializeData="System.Net.trace.log"
   traceOutputOptions = "ProcessId, DateTime"
            />
</sharedListeners>
<switches>
  <add name="System.Net" value="Verbose" />
  <add name="System.Net.Sockets" value="Verbose" />
  <add name="System.Net.Cache" value="Verbose" />
  <add name="System.Net.HttpListener" value="Verbose" />
</switches>
```

Answer (score 9):

I found the fix for this in this post:

https://www.daimto.com/azure-with-service-accounts-in-c/

Changing this line

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(keyFilePath, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
```

to

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(keyFilePath, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
```

Fixed my issue

Comment: This is a particularly good idea when using the certificate in a service environment (rather than as a user application)

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to know what your issue is without seeing your code but here is my code for service account authncation

```
   /// <summary>
    /// Authenticating to Google using a Service account
    /// Documentation: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#serviceaccount
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="serviceAccountEmail">From Google Developer console https://console.developers.google.com</param>
    /// <param name="serviceAccountCredentialFilePath">Location of the .p12 or Json Service account key file downloaded from Google Developer console https://console.developers.google.com</param>
    /// <returns>AnalyticsService used to make requests against the Analytics API</returns>
    public static AnalyticsreportingService AuthenticateServiceAccount(string serviceAccountEmail, string serviceAccountCredentialFilePath, string[] scopes)
    {
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath))
                throw new Exception("Path to the service account credentials file is required.");
            if (!File.Exists(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath))
                throw new Exception("The service account credentials file does not exist at: " + serviceAccountCredentialFilePath);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(serviceAccountEmail))
                throw new Exception("ServiceAccountEmail is required.");                

            // For Json file
            if (Path.GetExtension(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath).ToLower() == ".json")
            {
                GoogleCredential credential;
                using (var stream = new FileStream(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream)
                         .CreateScoped(scopes);
                }

                // Create the  Analytics service.
                return new AnalyticsreportingService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = "Analyticsreporting Service account Authentication Sample",
                });
            }
            else if (Path.GetExtension(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath).ToLower() == ".p12")
            {   // If its a P12 file

                var certificate = new X509Certificate2(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
                var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
                {
                    Scopes = scopes
                }.FromCertificate(certificate));

                // Create the  Analyticsreporting service.
                return new AnalyticsreportingService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = "Analyticsreporting Authentication Sample",
                });
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Unsupported Service accounts credentials.");
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {                
            throw new Exception("CreateServiceAccountAnalyticsreportingFailed", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Code ripped from [ServiceAccount.cs](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Google%20Analytics%20Reporting%20API/v4/ServiceAccount.cs)